# Парсер IMDB, проблема с сортировкой

Tags: python

Нужно отсортировать по алфавиту топ 250 фильмов. Использую метод sort() к списку movies. Выдает ошибку, что 2 и 10 фильм не на своих местах. Хелп[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в текстовом виде вместо скриншотов, пожалуйста.

Comment: вы сортируете строки. поэтому у вас после 1 будет идти 10, потом 11 и так далее, и только после 19 будет 2. Сортируйте числа, и  все будет нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сортируете строки. Это верное поведение Python при сортировке строк: после 1 будет 10, потом 11, и лишь потом, после 19 (или даже после 193), будет идти 20.